# cookieManager outside of activity

Tags: android, cookies, android-context

I'm trying to do some post request to a webpage containing json data... but there are cookies involved.

cookies are working fine but aren't persistent....

I'm doing the request from a separate class(object). I pass the activity context to that class but I'm still not able to store the cookies.

I tried using `cookiessyncmanager` to sync the cookies but this requires a `cookiemanger`. and that's where I'm stuck because the `cookiemanager` doesn't allow me to create a context like the `cookiesyncmanager` does...

here's my code:

```
    for(Cookie cookie : cookieStore.getCookies()){
            String cookieString = cookie.getName() + "="
            + cookie.getValue() + "; domain=" + cookie.getDomain();
        CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(cookie.getDomain(),
            cookieString);
        }
        CookieSyncManager.createInstance(baseContext).sync();
```

as you can see `CookieManager` allow allows the `getInstance()` method, but this just results in "failure" as the object obviously doesn't have a context....